# Trigger an asp.net user defined method on <a href> </a> click

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a Section  which is populated from code behind using a literal control.
Have assigned the literal as follows:

```
    literal1.Text+="<div class=\"section-cont\"><div class=\"category\"><ul class=\"cate-ul\"><li>
                   literal1.Text+=" <h3><span id=\"s\">"+ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["title"].ToString()+"</span></h3>";
                   literal1.Text+="<ul class=\"cate-ul\"><table id=\"tab\" cellspacing=\"0\" style=\"border-collapse:collapse;\">";
                 literal1.Text+="<tr><td> <li><a id=\"chaps\" href=\"\" >"+ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["titleSub"].ToString()+"</a></li>";
                  literal1.Text+="</td></tr></table> </ul></li></ul></div>";

In the above literal, there is `<a href>` as an `<li>`;how can i call an asp.net function() in this above <a> tag ???
```

Comment: Why not use a `LinkButton`? A `LinkButton` is basiclly an anchor tag, for which the plumbing of server-side and client-side code have been taken care of.

Comment: @Elad Lachmi: I need to used the above sample code to generate this section where in a link is also a part.Can i facilitate this basic link to call and asp function()??

Comment: Well than Izzy`s proposed solution should work for you. Something else is wrong. Maybe if you update your question with the markup and code, we can assist you further.

Comment: @EladLachmi: I tried the way lzzy specified but the function within the OnServerClick event is not triggering. :(

Comment: Did you make sure the function has the event handler signature? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58tf9b9h(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the function to the `<a>` tag. Just make it server control by adding `runat=server` to it

`<a href="#" runat="server" onServerClick="MyFuncion_Click" />`

Comment: i did like wise but did not get it.